# How can I understand "être témoin à" ?

Tags: prépositions

Content Warning: Mild mention of domestic violence.

---

The following is spoken by a social worker in Québec (from a documentary-like TV show) :

> Il y a eu aussi à ce moment-là de la violence un peu dans le domicile
> **à laquelle** votre garçon aurait **été témoin**.

On WordReference, I found an [entry](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/t%C3%A9moin) for "être témoin **de** [qch]", but not "être témoin **à** [qch]". Is "être témoin de [qch]" identicial to "être témoin à [qch]"?

In general, if I know that "être [noun] **de** [qch]" works, can I assume that "être [noun] **à** [qch]" can work, too?

Comment: Interesting. My instinct is to say no, it is not generalizable. Is this from a Canadian text? I do find that speakers here sometimes substitute à for de, e.g. a sentence I'll always remember on the radio because it was my first exposure to the phenomenon: "J'accepte les excuses à Martin." On the other hand, it takes quite a bit of effort to replace "dont" with "à laquelle", so it might be less plausible.

Comment: @LukeSawczak It is from a Québécois show,  Au cœur de la DPJ, which I think might be filmed near Montreal.

Comment: This is spoken, You can tell by the way the word peu is used and the fact the phrase à laquelle is not after the word violence. Anyway, **sometimes people switch pronouns in mid-stream** as the brain and tongue do not always work together. That's the nature of speech. Violence à laquelle votre garçon a du faire face, There are lots of examples of that faire face à la violence in France and Québec.

Comment: @Lambie Too bad you keep answering in comments instead of proper answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the person speaking was about to say *à laquelle votre garçon **aurait assisté*** but changed their mind in the middle of the sentence to switch to *votre garçon aurait **été témoin***.